# Javascript within Polymer (not targeting the right way)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, soundcloud, polymer

So I just started using Polymer, I want to build a custom SoundCloud player in this element. Somehow I keep getting following error:

> Uncaught Error: SC.Widget function should be given either iframe
>   element or a string specifying id attribute of iframe element.

That should mean I am not targeting the iframe the right way, but I can't think of another way to do so (since almost 4 hours).

**= My problem is** why `var iframe = $(".iframe");` doesn't target the iframe. I tried it outside of Polymer and it worked fine there.

breaker-stream.html:

```
<polymer-element name="breaker-stream" attributes="url">
    <template>
    <iframe class="iframe" width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="{{url}}"></iframe>
      <script>   
        var iframe = $(".iframe");
        var widget = SC.Widget(iframe);
      </script>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('breaker-stream', {
        url: ""
    });
  </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script> 
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot use jquery `$` to access elements inside a shadow-root the same way you do in the main document. This is well-documented, try searching.
2. Putting `<script>` tags inside your template is a bad idea, put element-script inside the prototype object (inside `Polymer()`).
3. It's also a bad idea to put `<script>` inside of `<polymer-element>`. They don't do anything special when put there, and should be outside that element instead.

Here is a working example (http://jsbin.com/xujole/4/edit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Polymer</title>

  <!-- web components polyfill for non-Chrome -->
  <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <breaker-stream url="http://api.soundcloud.com/users/1539950/favorites"></breaker-stream>

  <!-- from here down could be in an import -->

  <!-- need this to make Polymer elements -->
  <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <!-- don't load this twice -->
  <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script> 

  <polymer-element name="breaker-stream" attributes="url" block>
  <template>
    <iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url={{url}}"></iframe>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      url: "",
      ready: function() {
        this.widget = SC.Widget(this.$.frame);
      }
    });
  </script>
  </polymer-element>

</body>
</html>
```